# Text classification using java libsvm - model, parameter selection

Tags: java, machine-learning, libsvm

I'm trying to use the direct java port of [libsvm](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/index.html) for text classification.

Currently have bad accuracy and following [this guide](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/papers/guide/guide.pdf) to tune model.
At this stage have 2 doubts.

1. I do scaling by taking termcount/totalterms_in_doc. Will this be adequate?
2. When running `svm.svm_cross_validation` / `svm.svm_train` methods I get following output, what does it mean, how do I infer gamma and C from this?

   optimization finished, #iter = 1504
   nu = 0.5800464037122964
   obj = -299.9624358558652, rho = -0.9799716681242028
   nSV = 3000, nBSV = 3000
   Total nSV = 3000
   version of libsvm=3.2, java=1.7

Answer (score 4):

I assume you proceed for text classification as described in [1].

To obtain your feature values (simple scaling, no scaling, what ever you want), you have various possibilities [2].

**TFC** method works quite well [1], for details [2]:

```
TermFrequency * log(N/n) * 1 / sum((TermFrequency_i * log(N/n_i))^2)
```

with

```
sum => every term in your document collection; 
N => total number of documents; 
n => number of documents to which a term is assigned
```

The output originates from the training process. For training (assuming you are using the RBF kernel) the parameters gamma and C are on default values (if you do not provide them via CLI arguments) - same for CV.

To obtain the "best" gamma and C for your classification problem, you have to proceed with a grid-search (described in the linked guide). Afaik their is **no build-in functionality** for grid-search in LIBSVM.

[1] T. Joachims: Text Categorization with Support Vector Machines: Learning with Many Relevant Features; Springer: Heidelberg, Germany, 1998, doi:10.1007/BFb0026683

[2] G. Salton and C. Buckley. Term weighting approaches in automatic text retrieval. Information Processing and Management, 24(5):513{523, 1988.

Comment: I have been trying out with various scaling schemes, with variant results on enron spam datasets. Wonder how much training data is required to get good results. Also, any idea what scaling scheme does libSVM use?

Comment: Per "default" no scaling is done. If you're values cover huge intervalls, scaling to -1 to 1 may be useful. Accuracy depends first on your data, second on the selected features, tuned kernel parameters and last on the term weighting or scaling approaches.  How much documents are you using for training? How much categories? Any kind of preprocessing?